# Unable to use Viewgroup in my class

Tags: android, layout, view

If i try to use ViewGroup i'm getting this error `"ViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type"`.
There is no specific import present, how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should define a static class named ViewHolder. See this example. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: Thanks, you are right... But one question, why we should make ViewHolder as static class, what is the advantage of it?

Comment: I'm not quiet sure of that, but I think it's just because the ViewHolder class it related to the method getView(), and you should only use it inside. Like a struct in C.

Comment: I also found answer for that, its just remove the overhead.. if we make nested class as static, it does not create the instance of base class..